# WooCommerce Merge Categories in a Menu item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, categories, product

How would I make a menu item has two combined product categories like it functions as a filter in WooCommerce without using WordPress query?

---

Example: I have product categories "**Men**", "**Women**", **Kids**" and "**Shoes**".

---

I'd like to display my menu items:

```
Shoes
    Men
    Women
    Kids
```

or

```
Men
    Shoes

Women
    Shoes

Kids
    Shoes
```

But I'd like also the product category "**Shoes**" which shows all the shoes products in the first example

or

product category "**Men**" in the second example that shows all the men products such as Shoes, Shirts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can try that:

1. Create subcategory under the same category.

   - If you get data like excel, has to change there first.
2. You may create another category menu type like **Vertical menu-Top menu**  etc. Or you can get a mega menu app which has more option to use.